# Use of "suspicion" as verb

Tags: word-usage

My coworker says things like

> I **suspicion** that it happened the other day when nobody was here.

I would say

> I suspect it happened

or

> I have a suspicion that it happened.

What my coworker says sounds wrong to me. Is it common usage anywhere?

Comment: It sounds wrong to me too...

Comment: "I'm suspicious that it happened the other day..." comes to my mind.

Comment: It is non-standard and most native speakers will think you're making a mistake.

Comment: I agree (being a native speaker) and some dictionaries list it and some don't.

Comment: Folks, stop with the voting to close as general reference! Clearly, this is a case where general usage disagrees with information found in the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve never heard or read it used as such, but the OED has an entry for ‘suspicion’ as a verb, with supporting citations from the seventeenth to the twentieth century. Those cited include authors as diverse as John Buchan, C S Forester, Samuel Beckett, Rudyard Kipling and Carson McCullers.

Comment: So I think we all agree that this is not in current use even though it does appear in *some* dictionaries.  Do any of them list it as deprecated or antiquated or similar?

Comment: Mark Twain uses suspicion as a verb multiple times in his dialogue in "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn."

Answer (score 2):

Of course *I suspicion* sounds wrong. If we take as read that *suspicion* is a verb meaning *suspect*, then *I suspicion* is ungrammatical because *suspect* requires an object, so *suspicion* requires an object too.

You cannot just *suspect*, you must *suspect something*, much like you can't just *hate*, you must *hate something*. So you must *suspicion something*.

That said, despite *suspicion* being [cited as a verb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspicion), I have not heard it and I would not use it as such.

Comment: I think you've missed my point, my examples do contain objects: "I suspicion that it happened the other day when nobody was here" Your last sentence is apropos though. And I am in agreement with you there.

Comment: @Jim you said - "I suspicion" sounds wrong to me. This is what I'm explaining. As a stand alone utterance it is wrong.

Comment: Ok, what I meant was "I suspicion ..." as the beginning of a setence as demonstrated by my examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall ever hearing "suspicion" used as a verb. The conventional verb form is "suspect". I see thefreedictionary.com lists it as a "nonstandard verb". But that's a very rare usage.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. Dictionaries cite it back to 1861, and it's still in use.

According to [image: this Google ngram]
it seems to be rising in popularity since the last years of last century, though Google ngrams are not the best indicator of, well, anything.

Comment: Looking at the actual results 1970-2000 from your chart, I find there are less than a couple of dozen separate valid instances (plus duplicates, OCR misreadings of 1/a, etc.), and several of *those* seem to be quoting older text. I suspect the form doesn't exist today except among non-native speakers and perhaps a few dialectal hangovers.

Comment: ...going for another form, **We suspicion that** gets 19 hits in the past 60 years, as opposed to over 200,000 for **We suspect that**. Sorry, but I'm gonna have to downvote this. *Suspicion* is not meaningfully a verb.

Comment: **we** throws the results off.